# MinGW CMake make googletest with make error but no hit

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, mingw, googletest

I's m trying to compile gtest and gmock on windows10 with MinGW and Cmake;

Tools：

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.21.1

gcc -v
gcc version 8.1.0 

mingw32-make.exe -v
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

Build command as followed:

```
(base) PS D:\WorkSpace\Codes\GTest_GMock\googletest-master\build> cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=gnu++11
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Python: D:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/python.exe (found version "3.9.5") found components: Interpreter
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/WorkSpace/Codes/GTest_GMock/googletest-master/build

(base) PS D:\WorkSpace\Codes\GTest_GMock\googletest-master\build> mingw32-make.exe
[ 12%] Building CXX object googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj
系统找不到指定的路径。(cannot find path)
mingw32-make[2]: *** [googletest\CMakeFiles\gtest.dir\build.make:76: googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: *** Deleting file 'googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:171: googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:145: all] Error 2
(base) PS D:\WorkSpace\Codes\GTest_GMock\googletest-master\build>
```

Comment: Did you try it with "cmd" instead of Powershell? I cannot remember any problem, but we did not use Cmake.

Comment: I don't recommend you install content into paths containing whitespace, like `D:\Program Files`.  Make doesn't handle pathnames with whitespace very well.  I recommend you install your mingw directory into a path without whitespace.  I expect that will work much better.